# Custom Google search api parameters

Tags: java, google-search-api

I'm developing an application that uses Google search for specific keywords on specific domains. However, scraping Google result page and parsing results from HTML is not very "clean" approach, so I switched to Custom Google Search API. I managed to fetch results for a single keyword so far, but but I'm having trouble getting results for multiple keywords and multiple domains. In the settings of Custom Search I set it to do a whole web search, just to mention. So, my question is, how can search for multiple keywords on specific domains without setting it in developers console?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. This is current code:

```
package org.wonderland.dev.java;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Result;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Search;


public class GoogleSearchClient {

    final private String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    final private String SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = "00844xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx";

    public void printResults() {
            String searchKeyWord = "app";       
            List<Result> resultList = this.getSearchResult(searchKeyWord);
            if(resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0){
                   for(Result result: resultList){
                      System.out.println(result.getTitle());
                    } 
            }
    }


    public List<Result> getSearchResult(String keyword){
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null);

        List<Result> resultList = null;
        try {
            Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list(keyword);
            list.setKey(API_KEY);
            list.setCx(SEARCH_ENGINE_ID);
            list.setNum(10L);
            Search results = list.execute();
            resultList = results.getItems(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: I edited the question, you can see the code now.